# How to change justification of chapter and chapter title?

Tags: formatting, chapters

I am using the report package for writing my project report. However, I need to make few changes in the report package in order to meet the university guidelines. Currently I am facing difficulties in formatting the Chapter title. I need the title to be right aligned and of 18pt font size, and chapter heading to be center aligned and of 16pt font size.
I want output as
[image]

Please suggest any steps to do above things.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `titlesec` package. This code looks mor or less like your picture:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[explicit, indentafter]{titlesec}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\lsstyle\SetTracking[no ligatures = {f}]{encoding = *}{50}}
{\fontsize{18}{22}\selectfont\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\enspace\thechapter}
{3ex}
{\filcenter\fontsize{16}{20}\selectfont\MakeUppercase{#1}}%\titlerule[1.5pt]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-60pt}{5ex}
\titleformat{\section}
{\bfseries\lsstyle\SetTracking[no ligatures = {f}]{encoding = *}{50}}
{\thesection}
{3ex}
{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%\titlerule[1.5pt]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3.5ex}{2ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Motivation}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Another section}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am getting output as I wanted, but, header and footer are missing. What to do for that?

Comment: Could you describe what do you want to have exactly? It's easy to do with `titleps` (which belongs to the `titlesec` bundle).

Comment: I want output like this : https://goo.gl/KYQtvu